# how to project fake caustics on 2d image?

Tags: compositing-nodes, 2d, caustics

I have a 2d underwater background (see images attached) on which I would like to project some fake caustics (such as this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j17dGVw3_gM), could anyone recommend a good way of doing this?

I found that a lot of tutorials explaining how to create fake caustics work when there is geometry involved but I can't find anything when it is for 2d images.

Looking forward to hearing from you!

Thanks a lot!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "*Can't find anything when it is for 2d images.*" If your 2D image is part of 3D scene then surely it is applied in some form of geometry, even if it is a simple plane. If that is the case then the same techniques should apply, no?

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, you are right, I am trying now. I need to reprogramme my brain to think in terms of 3d as I came from a 2d background. Thank you!